# Vaadin GWT Widget Modification

Tags: gwt, widget, vaadin

I need to modify the GWT code of vaadin table widget. How do I begin ?. Where can I find the GWT code of the Table widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin widgetset sources are included in the .jar file since gwt compiler needs java source code to generate javascript. Hence normally you can access sources in your IDE, for instance in Eclipse pushing F3 over a method o class name in your code.

In Vaadin, server components are bundled in vaadin-server.jar, and client widget implementations in vaadin-client.jar. You have original code available at https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/

Normally the easier option for modifying a Vaadin widget is copying the code of the classes you want to modify in your project, using the same namespace, so the compiler will use them because of the classpath preference. Remember that you have to compile the widgetset each time you make modifications in client code.

But the recommended option is that you extends all the classes involved in that widget (server component, client classes) and use your own widgetset implementation. You have more info in the Book of Vaadin: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/clientside.widget.html